# Mapbox-gl in React.js app, TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFeatureState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Need to create a hover effect on my map, I'm doing it according to this tutorial:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

Unfortunately i I came up with an error which Im not able to solve, please see below the error stack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setFeatureState' of undefined
    at r.<anonymous> (Map.js:219)
    at r.delegates.o.<computed> (mapbox-gl.js:23210)
    at r.St.fire (mapbox-gl.js:915)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (mapbox-gl.js:23021)
```

Please see also the photo of the error page:
[image]

I am adding the source code below:

```
    setMapLayer(){

        if (!this.map.loaded() || this.state.searchedPhrase === '') return

        var contours = importContours(this.state.mapType)
        var contoursWithData = addData(contours, this.state.mapType, this.state.searchedPhrase)
        contoursWithData.then((data)=>{
            var mpSource = this.map.getSource("contours")

            if (typeof mpSource === 'undefined') 
                this.map.addSource('contours', { type: 'geojson', data })
            else 
                this.map.getSource("contours").setData(data)

            var mpLayer = this.map.getLayer("contours")

            if (typeof mpLayer === 'undefined') {
                this.map.addLayer({
                    id: 'contours',
                    type: 'fill',
                    source: 'contours',
                    layout: {},
                    paint: {
                        'fill-opacity': [
                            'case',
                            ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
                            0.7,
                            0.4
                        ]
                    }
                }, 'country-label-lg')

                this.map.addLayer({
                    id: 'state-borders',
                    type: 'line',
                    source: 'contours',
                    layout: {},
                    paint: {
                        'line-color': '#c44cc0',
                        'line-width': 0.5
                    }
                })
            }

            var hoveredStateId = null

            // When the user moves their mouse over the state-fill layer, we'll update the
            // feature state for the feature under the mouse.
            this.map.on('mousemove', 'contours', function(e) {
                if (e.features.length > 0) {
                    if (hoveredStateId) {
                        console.log('hoveredStateId ',hoveredStateId)
                        this.map.setFeatureState(
                            { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                            { hover: false }
                        )
                    }
                    console.log('e.features[0]',e.features[0])
                    console.log('e.features[0].id',e.features[0].id)
                    hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id
                    console.log('s',hoveredStateId)
                    this.map.setFeatureState(
                        { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                        { hover: true }
                    )
                }
            })

            // When the mouse leaves the state-fill layer, update the feature state of the
            // previously hovered feature.
            this.map.on('mouseleave', 'contours', function() {
                console.log('jestem 2')

                if (hoveredStateId) {
                    this.map.setFeatureState(
                        { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                        { hover: false }
                    )
                }
                hoveredStateId = null
            }) 

            console.log('jestem 3 ',hoveredStateId )
            this.setLegend(data)
            this.setFill() 


        })
    }
```

the console.logs are added for my debugging.

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are making a new function and creating a new instance of `this`. Change it to an arrow function -

```
this.map.on('mousemove', 'contours', (e) => {  //arrow function//
                if (e.features.length > 0) {
                    if (hoveredStateId) {
                        console.log('hoveredStateId ',hoveredStateId)
                        this.map.setFeatureState(
                            { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                            { hover: false }
                        )
                    }
                    console.log('e.features[0]',e.features[0])
                    console.log('e.features[0].id',e.features[0].id)
                    hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id
                    console.log('s',hoveredStateId)
                    this.map.setFeatureState(
                        { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                        { hover: true }
                    )
                }
            })
```

you will face same error in function that follows the above function change it to an arrow function as well -

```
   this.map.on('mouseleave', 'contours', () => {
            console.log('jestem 2')

            if (hoveredStateId) {
                this.map.setFeatureState(
                    { source: 'contours', id: hoveredStateId },
                    { hover: false }
                )
            }
            hoveredStateId = null
        }) 

        console.log('jestem 3 ',hoveredStateId )
        this.setLegend(data)
        this.setFill() 


    })
```

Comment: Thats correct. Can you please clarify why it makes a difference? Until this issue I thought that the "function () {}" equals "() => {}".

Comment: When you use `function () {}` to create a new function it creates it's own instance of `this`. Using the es6 arrow funtion doesn't not create a new instance of this and it uses it's parent's this.